# using event binding for selectbox (angular 9) .You can look at the gif

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular9

I would like the title to change to the selected value from the `select`, but I'm not sure how to do that.  This is the code I have so far:

**component.html**

```
<p>Team:</p>

<select (Change)="selectchange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let t of teams" [ngValue]="t" >
      {{t.team}}
  </option>
</select>
<h1>your team:<div>{{}}</div></h1>
```

**component.ts**

```
teams= [
    { team: 'Galatasaray', value: '4 yıldızlı tek takım' },
    { team: 'Fenerbahçe', value: '3 yıldızlı takım'},
    { team: 'Beşiktaş', value: '3 yıldızlı takım'}
];
```

[An example animation of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dhZW.gif)

Comment: Please add an actual question to your topic and what you've tried so far :)

Comment: I student .this is an actual question.i just want help.

Comment: For us to help you, we need a question. All you did now was dump some information and a gif. That is not a question :) I've editted your topic, the first line now is an actual question :)

Answer (score -1):

Use create a selectedTeam variable and bind it using `ngModel`.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTeam" (ngModelChange)="selectchange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let t of teams" [ngValue]="t" >
      {{t.team}}
  </option>
</select>
<h1>your team:<div>{{selectedTeam?.team + selectedTeam?.value}}</div></h1>
```

Comment: in type script you only have to implement variable `selectedTeam`. since its bind with `ngModal` it will update when ever the dropdown value changed

Comment: Can you write the codes because  I'm getting an error.

Comment: there is no code.just create a variable `selectedTeam` to bind to your ngModel. more about NgModel https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel